# Bash print date in one liner

Tags: bash, mongodb

I have a small bash one liner that hits mongo and gets some stats - and while that works fine I also want to get the date on the prefixed. Here's the current code that works:

```
--quiet --eval "db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function (n) { var s = db[n].stats(); print('namespace=' + s['ns'] +',count=' + s['count']+',avgObjSize=' + s['avgObjSize']+',storageSize=' + s['storageSize']) })"
```

Now I want to also print out the date before the name space so I tried a few things but couldn't get it to work... thoughts?

```
d="$(date +'%D %r %Z')"
```

I tired adding it in as a new VAR ...

```
{ var s = db[n].stats(); **var d="$(date +'%D %r %Z')";** print(**d**'namespace=' + s['ns'] +',count=' + s['count']+',avgObjSize=' + s['avgObjSize']+',storageSize=' + s['storageSize']) })"
```

but no such luck on the output

EDIT
Also tried adding it before the --eval and while the eval works on the mongo side I still can't get the date to print.

```
d="$(date +'%D %r %Z')" --quiet --eval "db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function (n) { var s = db[n].stats(); print('namespace=' + s['ns'] +',count=' + s['count']+',avgObjSize=' + s['avgObjSize']+',storageSize=' + s['storageSize']) })"
```

Comment: It is your local system date.

Comment: thats fine but I still want it to print out the date!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is your local bash that formats the date, so it is just a string in the javascript:

`--quiet --eval "db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function (n) { var s = db[n].stats(); print('d=$(date +'%D %r %Z') namespace=' + s['ns'] +',count=' + s['count']+',avgObjSize=' + s['avgObjSize']+',storageSize=' + s['storageSize']) })"`